# How to improve readability of code that transforms seconds to hours, minutes and seconds format

Tags: python-3.x

I got the code to do what I want, yet I feel its hardcoded than an actual solution. Any suggestions on how I could adjust the Hours, Minutes, Seconds variables to be more clear to the reader?

```
Input = int(input("Seconds: "))

Hours = Input // (60*60)
Minutes =  Input//(60) - (Hours*60)
Seconds = Input - (Minutes*60) - (Hours*60*60)
print(Hours,"Hours",Minutes,"Minutes",Seconds,"Seconds")
```

Comment: I'd suggest using the modulo operator.

Answer (score 0):

Use modulos instead of division. They're a little confusing at first, but they're *really* awesome.

```
def convert(seconds):
    secs = seconds%60
    mins = (seconds//60)%60
    hrs  = (seconds//3600)
    return (secs,mins,hrs)
```

From a code optimization standpoint, my code does a total of four arithmetic operations, whereas yours runs through 10. Additionally, the whole `(Hours * 60)` thing is a little difficult to understand. 
That's not to say your code is *bad*, just a little unclear. Though readability counts, your code is not so illegible as to be impossible to understand.

Answer (score 0):

Constants help readability. Also using modulo helps:

```
SEC_PER_MIN = 60
SEC_PER_HOUR = SEC_PER_MIN * 60

secs = int(input("Seconds: "))

hours = secs // SEC_PER_HOUR
remaining_seconds = secs  % SEC_PER_HOUR
mins =  remaining_seconds // SEC_PER_MIN
remaining_seconds %= SEC_PER_MIN
print(f"{hours} Hours, {mins} Minutes, and {remaining_seconds} Seconds")
```

or you can abuse the `time` module and have it handle all the logic:

```
import time
secs = int(input("Seconds: "))
result = time.strftime('%H Hours, %M Minutes, %S Seconds', time.gmtime(secs))
print(result)
```